# Error: no matching Route53Zone found for multple acm certificate for multiple websites in cloudfront

Tags: terraform, amazon-cloudfront, aws-acm

I am trying to setup multiple websites in cloudfront terraform configurations with one base domain and multiple subdomains:

I am trying to create individual distribution for each website with alternate names like this:

First step is to create ACM certificate so I created a module acm_certificate/main.tf

```
   data "aws_route53_zone" "public" {
    name = var.domain
    
}
resource "aws_acm_certificate" "this" {
  domain_name       = "www.${var.domain}"
  subject_alternative_names = ["www.${var.domain}", "${var.domain}"]
  validation_method = "DNS"
   lifecycle {
    create_before_destroy = true
  }
  
}

resource "aws_route53_record" "cert_validation" {
 
  allow_overwrite = true
  for_each = {
    for dvo in aws_acm_certificate.this.domain_validation_options : dvo.domain_name => {
      name    = dvo.resource_record_name
      record  = dvo.resource_record_value
      type    = dvo.resource_record_type
      zone_id = data.aws_route53_zone.public.id
    }
  }

  name            = each.value.name
  records         = [each.value.record]
  ttl             = 60
  type            = each.value.type
  zone_id         = each.value.zone_id

}
resource "aws_acm_certificate_validation" "this" {
  
  certificate_arn         = aws_acm_certificate.this.arn
  validation_record_fqdns = [for record in aws_route53_record.cert_validation : record.fqdn]
}
```

And this is my child module that should create ACM cert for base domain and subdomains sites/route53.tf

```
data "aws_route53_zone" "public" {
  name = var.domain # base domain route53
}

locals {
  subdomainsList = {

    for pv in var.project_version : pv.project => {
      subdomain_name = "${pv.project}.${var.domain}"
      #target_distribution    = aws_cloudfront_distribution.engagement_hub_subdomains[pv.project]
    }
  }
}

module "acm_certificate_domain" {
  source = "../../modules/acm_certificate" # for base domain tst.example.com
  domain = var.domain
  env    = var.env
  region = var.region
  dns_name = var.dns_name
  providers = {
    aws        = aws
    aws.global = aws.global
  }
}

module "acm_certificate_subdomain" {
  env    = var.env
  region = var.region
  dns_name = var.dns_name
  for_each = local.subdomainsList
  source   = "../../modules/acm_certificate" # for sub domains 
  domain   = each.value.subdomain_name
  providers = {
    aws        = aws
    aws.global = aws.global
  }
  
}
```

where
var.domain = example.com in TF cloud workspace variable
var.project_version =[{"project": "project1", "version": "v123.1"}]

error

```
Error: no matching Route53Zone found
with module.static_site.module.acm_certificate_subdomain["project1"].data.aws_route53_zone.public
on modules/acm_certificate/main.tf line 1, in data "aws_route53_zone" "public":
data "aws_route53_zone" "public" {
```

Comment: Do you have this domain `example.com`  or whatever the value of  `var.domain` created in your Route53 Hosted Zone?

Comment: Yes, it is already created . Now this error is gone when I added this zoneid = data.aws_route53_zone.public.id to calling modules